# how to preserve the order of images after selecting multiple from storage access framework in android?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I'm using android storage access framework for my image picker for uploading. This is my code

```
    Intent.createChooser(new 
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("image/*"), "Choose an image");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

    if (multiple) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INDEX, 0);
    }
```

When onActivityResult is called, parse it like belows.

```
final ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
    int takeFlags = data.getFlags();
    takeFlags &= (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    for(int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
            ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
            Uri dataUri = item.getUri();
            ....
    }
```

The problem is, when i select multiple images the order is strange.
If i select A, B, C and D in order, it returns like B, C, D, A in order.
I figured out it was because the selected items are ordering by the document id.
(For the example, If the document uri is content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A10473, It ordered by "3A10473")

The Storage Access Framework always works like this. Whatever user select in order, It returns items ordering by the document id. And I don't know what the document id is before getting result.

It's very important to preserve the ordering of selected items to me.
How can i make this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);`. Remove. Does not make sense.

Comment: "It's very important to preserve the ordering of selected items to me" -- then only ask for one at a time. There is no requirement for the Storage Access Framework UI to even *remember* the order of selection, let alone have that order impact the results that get delivered back to you.

Comment: Dont allow multiple. Let them select one by one. Or make your own picker. By the way: ACTION_GET_CONTENT has nothing to do with storage access framework. It works on old android versions too. ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is SAF only.

Comment: "It's very important to preserve the ordering of selected items to me" — this sounds like extremely ill-convinced requirement. Why do you *fix* the order after selection? Why not let the user reorder things anytime afterwards?

Comment: @user1643723 It's simple. Becuase make user doesn't have to reoder everytime selecting multiple. This is very uncomfortable.

Comment: @greenapps I know That's easy. But you know, you don't really want it if you gonna pick more than 10 images. Think about the instagram.

Comment: any solution on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I also needed this functionality and was able to get the desired behavior using  the [FishBun library on GitHub](https://github.com/sangcomz/FishBun).

After following the instructions for setting up the library I called this to invoke the image gallery:

```
FishBun.with(this)
   .setImageAdapter(GlideAdapter())                 
   .startAlbumWithOnActivityResult(loadImageRequestCode)
```

and onActivityResult I was able to get the Uri's in the order of the selection by calling:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        loadImageRequestCode -> {
            data?.let {
                val images = it.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Uri>(FishBun.INTENT_PATH)
                images?.forEach { p ->
                   ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```